# Python mechanize get forms error

Tags: python, mechanize

I am using Python 2.7 and Mechanize 0.2.5. I get an error when I try to access the forms on a page I am trying to scrape. I would like to fill in the forms and download the data. My code is

```
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
    br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;                         rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
    br.open('http://areaprofiler.gov.in')
    req = br.click_link(text='List of Elected Members')
    br.open(req)
    print br.forms()
    br.select_form(nr=0)
```

It doesn't matter if I use `br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())` or `br = mechanize.Browser()`.

```
>>> print br.forms()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 420, in forms
return self._factory.forms()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 557, in forms
self._forms_factory.forms())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 237, in forms
_urlunparse=_rfc3986.urlunsplit,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 844, in ParseResponseEx
_urlunparse=_urlunparse,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 981, in _ParseFileEx
fp.feed(data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 781, in feed
self.bs_base_class.feed(self, data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_beautifulsoup.py", line 690, in feed
SGMLParser.feed(self, text)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_sgmllib_copy.py", line 110, in feed
self.goahead(0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_sgmllib_copy.py", line 144, in goahead
k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_sgmllib_copy.py", line 302, in parse_starttag
self.finish_starttag(tag, attrs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_sgmllib_copy.py", line 347, in finish_starttag
self.handle_starttag(tag, method, attrs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_sgmllib_copy.py", line 387, in handle_starttag
method(attrs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 735, in do_option
_AbstractFormParser._start_option(self, attrs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 480, in _start_option
raise ParseError("OPTION outside of SELECT")
mechanize._form.ParseError: OPTION outside of SELECT
```

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently there is malformed HTML and mechanize doesn't like it. I don't know if there are options to make the parser more permissive. You could try Selenium.

Comment: Could it be some other issues besides malformed HTML. For example, a CSRF token?

Comment: I don't know how mechanize works, do you have a specific reason to think a CSRF token would cause a `ParseError`, saying there's an OPTION outside of SELECT?